# Why typing same command in macOS bash gives divergent result as in jenkins bash script

Tags: regex, bash, jenkins, ack

I'm setting up jenkins freestyle job with bash script build step with ack command, Why I am not getting same result as from command bash on macOS?

Jenkins is set up on this macOS. I am using sck 2.28 version. I have tried to specify exact path to SCK declaration.

```
DEVVER=$\(/usr/local/Cellar/ack/2.28/bin/ack /path/to/file/app.config.ts -o --match '(?<=devVersion = ")(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+)'\)
echo ${DEVVER}
```

Expected Output:

```
1.9.16
```

Actual Output:

```
/path/to/file/app.config.ts: line 1: export: `{': not a valid identifier
/path/to/file/app.config.ts: line 3: static: command not found
... (same for each line till 221;)
/path/to/file/app.config.ts: line 221: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: **homebrew** normally symlinks every binary it creates in `/usr/local/bin` so in general, if you put `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH, you can simply use `ack` and anything else **homebrew** installs without typing all that path with `/usr/local/Cellar/ack/2.28...` If you want to check, try `ls -l /usr/local/bin/ack`

Comment: I have tried it already but it still gives same effect, first there was a problem that I was not able to use **homebrew** from Jenkins accout. I have installed it first from root account. After changing access to homebrew I was able to use ack from Jenkins accout. When it did not help i tried  to install again ack from Jenkins account and it was installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/ack/2.28...`

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, you have an extraneous backslash after the first dollar sign. It should be `DEVVER=$(ack ...)`

Comment: Without it bracket will end after first closing bracket(regex) instead of last closing bracket for command(variable). Tried: `/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins277369741079369146.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'`

Comment: Even removing backslashes, this mentioned and this before last closing bracket gives output: `Empty changeset (manual trigger?), running build.`

Comment: You are also missing a final closing `)`

Comment: Where? $\*(*ack pathToFIle -o --match regex \*)*

Comment: Write a simple `ack` command first, like `ack ABC XYZ` and test it till it prints what you want, then surround it with `DEVVER=$(...)`.

Comment: (First cd to file location)Ok, I have tried to execute this command `ack app.config.ts -o --match '(?<=devVersion = ")(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+)'` as shell, but it gave such an output: `Empty changeset (manual trigger?), running build \n Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`. When i type this in bash on Mack it gives me output: 1.9.16

Comment: After some more inverstigation. I have wrote simple bash script  
`#!/bin/bash  
function getVersion()  
{  
 sudo chmod 777 /path/to/file/app.config.ts
 ack /path/to/file/app.config.ts -o --match '(?<=devVersion = ")(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+)'  
}  
value=\`getVersion\`  
echo "$value"`      When I run this script bash /path/to/script in bash it works but running it in jenkins returns empty value. No idea why

Comment: As a workaround solution (not too good one) I have changed a command. Now I use grep -E "regex" in which I have removed `?<=` and replaced `spaces` with `.` and cut the not matching characters in found line.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround solution (not too good one) I have changed a command. Now I use grep -E "regex" in which I have removed `?<=` and replaced `spaces` with `.` and cut the not matching characters in found line.